# I need help to solve relationship error and list options in a second select, according to the value entered in the first select

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I need help to solve relationship error and list options in a second select, according to the value entered in the first select

In the browser console I have the following error when selecting the first "select".

get_communes?selected_region=ATACAMA:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

My objective is to select a region in the first selection, then in the second select the options in that region

I'm working with ruby ​​on rails, javascript, jQuery, bootstrap

request.js

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {


    //============ traer comuna de acuerdo a la region 
    $('#request_region').on('change', function (e) {
        var request_region = $('#request_region').find(":selected").text();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/requests/get_communes',
            type: 'get',
            data: {selected_region: request_region},
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('correcto!!');

                console.log(data);


                $("#request_commune").children().remove();
                var listitems = []; 
                $.each(data, function(key, value) { 
                    listitems += '<option value="' + value['id']+ '">' + value['name'] + '</option>'; 
                }); 
                $("#request_commune").append(listitems);
            }
        });
    });


    $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();

});
```

new.html.erb

```
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                <%= f.select :region_id, @regions, {include_blank: 'Elija una región'}, {class: 'js-example-basic-single', id: :request_region, required: true} %>
                <%= f.label :Región, class:'' %>
            </div>


            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">

                    <span class="custom-dropdown last">
                        <select class="js-example-basic-single" id="request_commune" data-live-search="true" name="request[commune_id]"
                        required>
                        <option value="AL">Primero Elija una Región</option>
                    </select>
                    <%= f.label :comuna, class:'' %>

            </div>
```

folder: requests (devise)
registrations_controller-rb

```
    def new
        @regions = Region.all.collect { |reg| [reg.name, reg.id] }
        super
    end
```

requests_controller.rb

```
class RequestsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_request!
  before_action :set_request, only: [:show, :edit, :update] # probably want to keep using this

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @requests = Request.all
  end

  # # GET /users/1
  # # GET /users/1.json
  def show

  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit

  end

  # # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @request.update(request_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @request, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @request }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @request.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  #def dashboard
    #corregir este método
    #data_certificacion = Event.find_by(request: current_request)
    #byebug
    #if data_certificacion.present?
     # @certification = true
    #end
  #end


  def get_communes
        region = Region.find_by(name: params[:selected_region])
        @communes = Commune.order(name: :asc).where(region_id: region.id)
    render json: @communes
  end


  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_user
    @request = Request.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def user_params
    params.require(:request).permit(:role, :name)
  end

end
```

relationships and models

```
region:
  has_many :communes

commune
  belongs_to :region
  has_many :requests

Schema:


  create_table "requests", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.string "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string "unconfirmed_email"
    t.integer "failed_attempts", default: 0, null: false
    t.string "unlock_token"
    t.datetime "locked_at"
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "phone"
    t.text "comment"
    t.boolean "state"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "region_id"
    t.bigint "commune_id"
    t.index ["commune_id"], name: "index_requests_on_commune_id"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_requests_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["region_id"], name: "index_requests_on_region_id"
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_requests_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end


  create_table "regions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end


  create_table "communes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.bigint "region_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["region_id"], name: "index_communes_on_region_id"
  end
```

Comment: What makes you think it's a relationship error when your server is returning `401 (Unauthorized)`?

Comment: @jvillian 
I'm not sure, the server shows the following:

Started GET "/ requests / get_communes? Selected_region = ATACAMA" for :: 1 at 2019-04-24 15:21:21 -0400
Processing by RequestsController # get_communes as * / *
  Parameters: {"selected_region" => "ATACAMA"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: Does your `ApplicationController` also include `before_action :authenticate_request!`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to generate and pass an auth token to the ajax call, something like:

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
   xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", token ));
},
```

Check jQuery's [beforeSend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) directive.

Comment: Out of curiosity... This would require, wouldn't it, that `token` is available on the client side? And, if so, wouldn't that mean that `token` would be available to anyone who wanted to look at the js code in the browser?

Comment: It would require a mechanism to generate a unique token for each user (maybe using asymetric jwt?). So even if he looked at the source code, he would see his own token. This is required, since he tries to retrieve ajax data from a protected source.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue what do you have is here `before_action: authenticate_request!`, I think if you will remove this code from your controller, your `get_communes` will return you JSON!

"before_action :authenticate_request!" suppose use only in `AuthenticationController` or `ApplicationController`!